# How can I show range of data in some other formats like Week-To-Date, Month To Date etc in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using `angular-highcharts`, in that I am using stock charts. In stock chart, if we don't provide custom ranging then automatically it will give 6 options by default like 1M, 3M, 6M etc which works perfectly. But I want to display range like WTD (Week-To-Date), MTD (Month-To-Date) etc.
Any suggestions on how to get it?
Thank You.

Comment: Have a look at https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.buttons

Comment: Can you explain what should be the expected result for a button, e.g. WTD?

Comment: thank you @morganfree for replying, I want something result like suppose current date is 8th of march i.e. Thrusday so WTD should display the data from starting day i.e 5th of march Monday till 8th of march. i.e. starting week day upto current day.

Comment: I think in this case you should build your own buttons and manipulate data by setting axis extremes and/or grouping - https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes, https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setDataGrouping